# Yii2: ActiveForm: множественный выбор для checkboxList и dropDownList (со значениями в переменной)

Tags: yii2

Сгенерировал для продуктов в админки, модель, контроллер и вьюшки, с помощью Gii. 
Изменил запрос, для получения модели:

`$model = Product::find()->with('sizes')->where(['products.id' => $id])->one();`

Размеры для продукта получаю через связь:

```
public function getSizes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Size::className(),['id' => 'size_id_ref'])
            ->viaTable(Value::tableName(), ['product_id_ref' => 'id']);
}
```

Получается у меня в `$model->sizes` массив объектов (со свойствами id и name)

Для размеров в ActiveForm сделал вывод всех значений из базы

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'pr_sizes')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\Size::find()->all(), 'id', 'name')) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'pr_sizes')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\Color::find()->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name'), ['multiple'=>'multiple']) ?>
```

Подскажите, как мне в файле _form.php сделать `dropDownList` или `checkboxList` с мультивыбором, так чтоб соответствующие продукту размеры сразу подставились в форму. И далее чтобы эти размеры можно было обновлять (записывать в таблицу значений value по id продукта).

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы указать выбранные пункты, необходимо в атрибуте `pr_sizes` перечислить значения которые выбраны, то есть их `id`.

Как вариант:

```
$model->pr_sizes = ArrayHelper::getColumn($model->sizes, 'id');
```

Конечно же pr_sizes должен существовать в вашей модели, или быть полем в таблице или быть объявленным в классе - `public $pr_sizes = [];`

Comment: хороший вариант, спасибо! Теперь остается вопрос как сохранить изменения в чексбоксах, чтоб данные записались в соответствующую таблицу БД (в моем случаи value)